# Auto adjust width and height in zenity

Tags: zenity

Do we have an option in zenity to auto adjust the width and height of the results window instead of manually specifying the values of height & width ?

Answer (score 2):

Using this script:

Install `x11-utils`, we need `xwininfo`

```
sudo apt-get install x11-utils
```

and create a script with the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
# resizes the window to full height and 50% width and moves into upper right corner

#define the height in px of the top system-bar:
TOPMARGIN=27

#sum in px of all horizontal borders:
RIGHTMARGIN=10

# get width of screen and height of screen
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(xwininfo -root | awk '$1=="Width:" {print $2}')
SCREEN_HEIGHT=$(xwininfo -root | awk '$1=="Height:" {print $2}')

# new width and height
W=$(( $SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - $RIGHTMARGIN ))
H=$(( $SCREEN_HEIGHT - 2 * $TOPMARGIN ))

zenity --entry --ok-label=sure --width=$W --height=$H
```

<sub>[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53228/107084)</sub>